# Is there a way to get a reference to results after creating word documents using mail merge?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, visual-studio-addins, mailmerge

I'm using a VSTO 2010 AddIn to do a Word mail merge with WdMailMergeDestination being set to wdSendToNewDocument. Is there any way to get a reference to the newly created documents or even find out which data row was used to create each one?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Christopher i am working on the same thing and so far i have managed to create an add-in for the outlook. So the Word mail merge completes and the mail in the Outlook outbox folder, right before being sent will attach the attachment of any type.
I am using this for mass scale i am talking about 5000-7000 mails at one go, and the add-in failed me, by attaching to only some emails its like on and off (my guess is the add-in not able to handle the heavy duty). So now i am going a bit further in to the solution by capturing the mailmerge object in the word. (btw i am using i am developing for 2007 should be no problem for 2010 as well)
So far i can suggest you this article that i managed to dig if you have a found a solution please do share tks.
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;301659

P.S: I know that there are people selling this kind of software commercially.But its best if homebrewed!